# Twitter Bootstrap TypeAhead to work like DropDown List / Select Tag with Autocomplete Feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I want to have a DropDown List / < Select > HTML Tag behaviour with AutoComplete Feature using Twitter Bootstrap TypeAhead.  The link [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21368/bootstrap-combobox/index.html?) achieves the feature of Combo Box where user can provide his own input also.  I want to restrict the User to select only from the option provided.  Is there any way to tweek the Twitter Bootstrap TypeAhead Plugin to emulate the behaviour of DropDown List /  Tag with Autocomplete Feature.

I have referred the Following question before posting

1. [Adding a dropdown button to Twitter bootstrap typeahead component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689830/adding-a-dropdown-button-to-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-component)

Comment: Have you looked at [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) ? Not Twitter Bootstrap but maybe an alternative ?

Comment: @Sherbrow +1. But I am using [HandsOnTable](http://warpech.github.com/jquery-handsontable) which uses TB Typeahead so I have to find the solution using TypeAhead Only

Answer (score 24):

I just found this awesome plugin that turns a standard SELECT element into very seamless nicely styled combo box using bootstrap typeahead. It looks really good, I'm going to use it on my next project.

https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox

[Live Example](https://bootstrap-combobox-test.herokuapp.com/) (Bootstrap 3)

Comment: Anyone using this with the default ASP.NET Web Forms template (VS2013), there's a rule in `Site.css` that sets `max-width: 280px;` for `input` elements, which can your comboboxes look ugly if they're wider than 280 pixels.

Answer (score 10):

Tiny improvement to davidkonrads answer to keep the filter functionality when typing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#test").typeahead({
    "source": ['Pennsylvania', 'Connecticut', 'New York', 'Maryland', 'Virginia'],
    //match any item
    matcher: function(item) {
        if (this.query == '*') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return item.indexOf(this.query) >= 0;
        }
    },
    //avoid highlightning of "*"
    highlighter: function(item) {
        return "<div>" + item + "</div>"
    }
});

// "select"-button
$(".showAll").click(function(event) {
    var $input = $("#test");
    //add something to ensure the menu will be shown
    $input.val('*');
    $input.typeahead('lookup');
    $input.val('');
});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d4kris/5rtGA/3/

Comment: if you check `if($input.data('typeahead').shown == true) { // hide } else { //show }` you can turn showAll into a toggle button.

Comment: Okay, even more of an improvement on this code, to preserve highlighting and case insensitive searching: http://jsfiddle.net/kappamax/XKnfX/ I hope that helps someone else.

Answer (score 6):

That is indeed possible - even very simple - without changing the typeahead javascript / using altered code, *IF* you are willing not to show matched results highlighted.

HTML:

```
<input name="test" id="test"/>
<button id="emu-select" class="btn btn-small" type="button">
<i class="icon-arrow-down"></i>
</button>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#test").typeahead({
        "source": ['Pennsylvania','Connecticut','New York','Maryland','Virginia'],
        //match any item
        matcher : function (item) {
            return true;
        },
        //avoid highlightning of "a"
        highlighter: function (item) {
            return "<div>"+item+"</div>"
        }
    });

    // "select"-button
    $("#emu-select").click(function(){
        //add something to ensure the menu will be shown
        $("#test").val('a');
        $("#test").typeahead('lookup');
        $("#test").val('');
    });
});
```

working code / example at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/davidkonrad/ZJMBE/3/

Comment: JSFiddle no longer works, btw