# Twitter Bootstrap 3:- Typeahead and Selectbox Combo

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, plugins, combobox, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

Now that we have Twitter Bootstrap 3, are the plugins catching up?

Is there a typeahead-selectbox combo for bootstrap 3, something like [enter link description here](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21368/bootstrap-combobox/index.html).

Answers shown in [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745422/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-to-work-like-dropdown-list-select-tag-with-autocom?answertab=active#tab-top) are outdated as they use 2.3.x version of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of plugins are catching up to Bootstrap 3.
As far as typeahead comboboxes:

Select2's port to BS was recently updated to fit BS3: http://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/

MagicSuggest was recently updated to fit BS3: http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest

(disclaimer: i'm the author of the magicsuggest plugin)